# chrome extension auto-update from a local server

Tags: google-chrome-extension, auto-update

I have created a chrome extension for the company I work for, and want to post updates to a local server within the office network.
I have read http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/autoupdate.html, but to no avail.

**manifest.json**

```
{
  "name": "My Helper",
  "version": "1.0",
  "description": "desc",
  "omnibox": { "keyword" : "bla" },

  "update_url": "\\\\serverName\\Dir\\updates.xml",
  "background_page" : "background.html",
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "popup": "popup.html"
  },

  "permissions":
     ["tabs"]
}
```

**updates.xml**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<gupdate xmlns='http://www.google.com/update2/response' protocol='2.0'>
  <app appid='abpjmfcmljpfhjpalecklgnndibgnjmp'>
    <updatecheck codebase='\\serverName\Dir\my_helper.crx' version='1.0' />
  </app>
</gupdate>
```

Now, after I make some changes, I do the following:

- Update the version in *manifest.json* to 1.1
- Update the version in *updates.xml* to 1.1
- Pack the extension, specifying the directory which holds the source files and the *pem* file.
- Post the new *crx* file and the new *updates.xml* file to `\\serverName\Dir\`
- Go to another computer on the network, and click *update extensions now* in the Chrome's extensions window.

-> Nothing happens.

Question is - how to make an extension auto-update from a shared server on the local network?

P.S. I am pretty sure this is *not* a permissions issue. I have made sure I can access `\\serverName\Dir\` from all clients on this network.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK Network URL's are not supported. Host a simple HTTP server (there are many out there), and link directly to that instead.

Comment: I sense a feature request coming in 5..4..3..2..1.. DONE

Comment: It is a nice feature, but how will Unix clients (since we support Mac and Linux) read such thing? Sure we can use cifs/samba. But they are not default implementations on unix platforms. Instead of relying on network shares, it is more efficient to rely on any other layer such as HTTP (which is the easiest to setup).

Comment: There are other protocols which can access a remote computer on a LAN network, but you are correct. If it's not natively supported through the OS it is a problem. I had no idea that Unix clients won't know how to deal with that issue.

Answer (score 1):

yep you could put the update on a live but private server with some ridiculous sub-domain or domain name and even further add a random dir name or two if your worried about it going public