# Chrome extension mv3 - How to update private extension that is not in web store

Tags: firebase, google-chrome-extension, google-cloud-storage, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I've found this [old question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5842205/chrome-extension-auto-update-from-a-local-server) because I'm looking for a way to update a chrome extension that is not distributed on chrome web store and is private.

I've tried the same way that is into the linked question, but seems not working with mv3?Sometime I also have problems with CSP for RTDB (but it's another problem..)

Is there a modern way to achive the result?maybe a nodejs script?

Comment: Does this help you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30245932/how-do-i-check-if-a-google-chrome-extension-needs-to-be-updated

Comment: @ojonasplima it's not what I'm looking for